# .htaccess to prevent from direct access to files, but allowing <script src = , how to?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, http, src

I have an application with php , html , js  , ( /homesec )
.php files are in a controler directory , ( /homesec/controler )
.js and .phtml files are in a vue directory , ( /homesec/vue )

I must allow use of some url ,
and refuse use of others ( with a 403 )
allowed : https://...../homesec/controler/home.php
forbiden ( 403 ) : https://...../homesec/vue/home.js
and I need the .phtml files call their .js files like this :
allowed :   (in /vue/home.phtml )

to do it i created a /homesec/vue/.htaccess , with :
Require all denied
Require ip ::1

and it doesn't work
on my dev pc ( wampserver )

works , it's OK
https://...../homesec/vue/home.js works  , it's bad
on the prod server 
 fails , it's bad
https://...../homesec/vue/home.js fails  , it's OK
so it seems it also depends on the apache server ...

the question is , how to prevent urls with direct access to .js files with .htaccess
but still allow the  syntax in the .phtml files

Comment: how can you give access and prevent access to clients both at the same time? this question doesn't make any sense. why would you even want to prevent access to a js file. there should be nothing security sensitive in a js file, unless it's a server side only script using Node or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective way to supply a JS file to a browser while preventing the owner of the browser from accessing the source code of that JS file.

The closest you could come would be to examine the [Referer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) but that is:

- Unreliable
- Would not stop the user monitoring the data in the Network tab of their browser
- Would not stop the user accessing the URL if it was already in their browser cache
- Might cache a Forbidden error and deny access when the HTML document is subsequently visited